# How to paste copied picture into placeholder?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have copied a picture from another slide and now want to paste it into a blank (picture or content) placeholder on the active slide. I'll loop through the shapes looking for such a blank placeholder, but can it then be coded to paste the picture into the placeholder? I don't know how to code that part, if it's even possible.

Thanks,
Mel Turco

Comment: Can you post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example]), please? We don't know what slide you're using, or the code that you want to copy and paste.

Answer (score 1):

if you already copied why not simply paste it?

```
    ActivePresentation.Slides(slidenum).Shapes(copiedimage).Copy
    ActivePresentation.Slides(slidenum).Shapes(placeholdernum).Select
    ActivePresentation.Slides(slidenum).Shapes.Paste
```

this code works for me.

first line copies image, as shape, second selects place holder in which image should be pasted, and third one pastes it in selected placeholder

Answer (score 1):

After selecting the chosen Placeholder use

```
    ActiveWindow.View.Paste
```